# how to call a function in C?

Tags: c, function

This is my `main`:

```
int main(void){

    int ask_height(void);
    void pyramid(int num_rows);

}
```

I am unable to call `int ask_height(void)` and `void pyramid(int num_rows)` from `main`,
code for `int ask_height(void)`:

```
int ask_height(void){
      int num_rows;
    do{
        num_rows = get_int("height: \n");
    }
    while(num_rows < 1 || num_rows >8);

    return num_rows;
}
```

code for `void pyramid(int num_rows)`:

```
void pyramid(int num_rows){
    for (int i = 1; i<=num_rows; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=num_rows-i; j++){
            printf(" ");
            }
        for(int k= 1; k<=i; k++){
            printf("#");
            }
        printf(" ");
         for(int col=1; col<= i; col++ ){
            printf("#");
            }
        printf("\n");
        }

}
```

Comment: Look at how you call `get_int`, and `printf`, then look at how you call `pyramid` and `ask_height`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: yes that helped me and now it works perfectly. Thanks.